# WPF, How to check if the cursor has a file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm wondering how in the Windows environment the cursor is holding the icon on the desktop and getting the status of that icon.

For example, when I grab a file on the desktop and drag it, I want to figure out the properties of this file, such as its name and extension.

Answer (score 1):

WPF Controls can have the EventHandler `DragEnter` for checking this.

```
<ListView x:Name="DropList" 
          Drop="DropList_Drop" 
          DragEnter="DropList_DragEnter" 
          AllowDrop="True" />     


private void DropList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) // checks for File
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }
}
```

And with `Data.GetDataPresent()` you can convert the content to a specific format and then access properties of it.

Important is to note, everything could be your *grabbed Object*, like Files, Folders, List-Objects in your Application. You have to check this first, and allow it.

Then you can read the File in the `Drop` implementation with `System.IO.FileInfo`.

```
private void DropList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        // loop through files..
    }
}
```